# filter category Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to make a button to filter product by category.. Example Salad or Meat. Without Model ProductAtribuut im able to do it, but now i added the model, so im real confused how i can get the data of a Foreign Key inside a Foreign Key

ProductAtribuut  ->  Product(FK)  ->  Categorie(FK)

**Models.py**

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=150,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['naam']

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-naam',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.naam

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('JavaKitchen:product_by_categorie', args=[self.slug])

    @property
    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(categorie__naam=self.naam)


class Groente(models.Model):
    groente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.groente

class Vlees(models.Model):
    vlees = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vlees

class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    beschrijving = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        ordering=('-titel',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titel

    def get_title_uppercase(self):
        return self.titel.upper()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('JavaKitchen:product_detail',args=[self.id,])

class ProductAtribuut(models.Model):
    def groente():
        return Groente.objects.filter(groente='geen').first()
    
    def vlees():
        return Vlees.objects.filter(vlees='geen').first()

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    groente = models.ForeignKey(Groente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=groente)
    vlees = models.ForeignKey(Vlees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=vlees)
    prijs = models.FloatField(default=0)
    afbeelding = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='gerechten/') #later upgrade..
    zichtbaar = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.titel

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="80" height="auto" />' % (self.afbeelding))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

**Views.py**

```
def product_list(request,categorie_slug=None):
    categorie = None 
    javakitchen = JavaKitchen.objects.get(id=1)
    openings_tijden = Openings_tijden.objects.all()

    categories = Categorie.objects.all().filter(zichtbaar=True)
    product = Product.objects.all()
    productatribuut = ProductAtribuut.objects.all().filter(zichtbaar=True)

    if categorie_slug:
        categorie = get_object_or_404(Categorie,slug=categorie_slug)
        product = productatribuut.filter(product=product)

    context = { 'categories':categories, 
                'categorie':categorie, 
                'product':product, 
                'form':form, 
                'javakitchen':javakitchen, 
                'openings_tijden': openings_tijden,
                'productatribuut': productatribuut
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

**HTML template**

```
<div class="categories">
    <h1>{% if categorie %}{{ categorie.naam }}{% else %} ALLE GERECHTEN {% endif %}</h1>
    <ol class="type"> 
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href='{% url "JavaKitchen:product_list" %}#dinner'>Alles</a></li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}#dinner">{{ c.naam }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I used this before to get the category. when i didnt have **class ProductAtribuut**

```
if categorie_slug:
    categorie = get_object_or_404(Categorie,slug=categorie_slug)
    product = product.filter(categorie=categorie)
```

but now i dont know how i do get the category 
ProductAtribuut -> Product(fk) -> Categorie(fk)

Comment: See the documentation for [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) e.g. `ProductAtribuut.objects.filter(product__categorie=categorie)`. I can't provide an exact example because I can't figure out what the desired output is.

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly what i was looking for.. <3